# how I change the cell color clicking on it with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this, as I'm not a front-end programmer, I have a table, the lines are my clients nad the collumns are the twelve months of the year, each cell has only a checkbox, as i click on the checkbox, I need the cell collor to turn from red to blue, I did it, but only works for january...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    function countDouble(id) {      
        var d = $(".check-"+id+"-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>").is(':checked');

        if (d === true) {
            $(".celula-"+id+"-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>").prop("disabled",true).addClass('check-azul');
        } else {
            $(".celula-"+id+"-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>").prop("disabled",false).removeClass('check-azul');
        }

    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click( function() {
            var id = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('id');
            countDouble(id);
        });
    });
});//]]>
```

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $dado->nomeCliente; ?> <br>
            R$ <?php echo $dado->mensalidade; ?>,00 <br>
            Vence: <?php echo $dado->vencimento; ?>
        </td>
        <?php if($dado->ano == date("Y") && $dado->mes == '1'){ ?>
        <td class="check-meses check-vermelho check-azul celula-1-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>">
            Janeiro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="check-1-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>" name="janeiro" value="1" checked>
            <?php }else{ ?>
        <td class="check-meses check-vermelho celula-1-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>">
            Janeiro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="check-1-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>" name="janeiro" value="1">
        <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <?php if($dado->ano == date("Y") && $dado->mes == '2'){ ?>
        <td class="check-meses check-vermelho check-azul celula-2-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>">
            Fevereiro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="check-2-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>" name="fevereiro" value="2" checked>
            <?php }else{ ?>
        <td class="check-meses check-vermelho celula-2-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>">
            Fevereiro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="check-2-id-<?php echo $dado->idCliente; ?>" name="fevereiro" value="2">
        <?php } ?>
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Março <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Abril <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Maio <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Junho <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Julho <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Agosto <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Setembro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Outubro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Novembro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
        <td class="check-meses">
            Dezembro <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="janeiro">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the reason why your code works only for the first checkbox is this line:

```
var id = $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('id');
```

It returns the id of the first checkbox, not of the recently clicked one. Try to replace it with this line instead:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem, with just one word! Thank you, a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgray');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9etqyb84/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
        // detect if is checked or unchecked when this click is performed
        var checkedStatus = $(this).prop('checked'); // true or false

        if( checkedStatus ) {
            $(this).parent('td').css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else {
            $(this).parent('td').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    })
});
```

CSS

```
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```